# I can't fetch all the users to update a data table when removing a user as admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, material-ui

So basically I am working on Admin Dashboard and there is a section for users, it's simple, it only has a table to display all the users in the MongoDB database and show some info, it also has a function to directly add a new user and also to delete an existing user. That's where the issue is.

When I delete a user, he is removed from the db but it stays displayed on the data table until I refresh the page or click refresh button which basically just fetches the data again but I want to be able to call the refresh table function(Which is just a fetch from the db) inside a function where I delete the user so it automatically refreshes when I delete a user.

The problem is that the function for deleting users cannot call the fetchUsers function because it's inside the Users const which is exported so I have no way to call it.

I tried to move fetchUsers function outside of Users const but I cannot do that because fetchUsers depends on setUserRows (UseState) and I also tried to put the function for deleting the user in the User const but I also cannot do that because it is already used outside of User.

Here is my code:

````
import DataTable from "../dataTable/DataTable"
import "./userspagedb.scss"
import {useEffect, useState} from "react"
import Add from "../addUser/Add"

import axios from "axios";
import AddUserBtn from "../../../Buttons/addUserBtn/addUser";
import AddUserForm from "../../../Buttons/addUserForm/addUserForm";

import { userRows } from "../../data"
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

const getUser = async (userId) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.delete(`/api/auth/deleteUser/${userId}`, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

const columns = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 250 },
    // {
    //     field: "img",
    //     headerName: "Avatar",
    //     width: 100,
    //     renderCell: params => {
    //         return <img src={params.row.img || "/noavatar.png"} alt="" />
    //     }
    // },
    {
        field: "username",
        type: "string",
        headerName: "Username",
        width: 120
    },
    {
        field: "email",
        type: "string",
        headerName: "Email",
        width: 200
    },
    {
        field: "phoneNumber",
        type: "number",
        headerName: "Phone",
        width: 120
    },
    {
        field: "createdAt",
        headerName: "Created At",
        width: 100,
        type: "string"
    },
    {
        field: "verified",
        headerName: "Verified",
        width: 70,
        type: "boolean"

    },
    {
        field: "action",
        headerName: "Actions",
        width: 100,
        renderCell: (params) => {
            return (
                <div className="action">
                    <Link to="">
                        <img src="/Dashboard/view.svg" alt="" />
                    </Link>
                    <div className="delete" onClick={() => getUser(params.row.id)}>
                        <img src="/Dashboard/delete.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        },
    }
]

const Users = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
    const [userRows, setUserRows] = useState([]);


    const fetchUsers = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get('/api/auth/allUsers');
            const usersWithId = res.data.data.map(user => ({
                ...user,
                id: user._id,
                verified: user.isVerified ,
                phone: user.phoneNumber

            }));
            setUserRows(usersWithId);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUsers().then(r => console.log(userRows));
    }, []);

    const toggleModal = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
    };

    return (
        <div className="users">
            <div className="info">
                <h1>Users</h1>
                <button className="add-user-btn" onClick={fetchUsers}><h4>Refresh</h4></button>
                <AddUserBtn onClick={toggleModal} />
            </div>
            <DataTable slug="users" columns={columns} rows={userRows} />

            {open && <AddUserForm setOpen={setOpen} />}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Users;```
````

Comment: Currennty you are updating the backend, but that update does not reflect on the frontend. In other words you need to update a state variable to trigger the component to rerender. I suggest you wrap the `fetchUsers` function inside a `useEffect`, and in the dependency array add userid

Answer (score 1):

u need to synchronize userRows state with your useEffect, so it runs each time userRows state updates. To synchronize the userRows state with the useEffect, add it to the useEffect's dependency array.

```
// Change this, This effect will only run after the initial render.
useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers().then(r => console.log(userRows));
}, []);

// To this, This effect will now execute after both the initial render and the userRows state updates.
useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers().then(r => console.log(userRows));
}, [userRows]);
```

now each time userRows updates this effect will run.